# What makes a dynamic user unable to read personal files?

Tags: linux, permissions, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using a DNS service named [dnscrypt-proxy](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy). And I use the PPA to install it on Ubuntu 18.04. Here is the installed service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=DNSCrypt-proxy client
Documentation=https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki
Requires=dnscrypt-proxy.socket
After=network.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
NonBlocking=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dnscrypt-proxy --config /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes

# Run dnscrypt-proxy as unprivileged user with
# temporary assigned UID/GID. See man:systemd.exec
# for more info. Requires systemd 232+.
DynamicUser=yes
CacheDirectory=dnscrypt-proxy
LogsDirectory=dnscrypt-proxy
RuntimeDirectory=dnscrypt-proxy

[Install]
Also=dnscrypt-proxy.socket
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I give a file path `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy/blacklist.txt` in that `dnscrypt-proxy.toml` file as a blacklist which is a symbolic link points to my home directory `/home/user/.dnscrypt-proxy-config/blacklist.txt`.

The reason why I did this is that `blacklist.txt` comes from the internet, so I only want to put it in my personal directory to keep safety.

But the problem is, this service fails because of `Open blacklist.txt failed: Permission denied.` While I don't understand which part causes this problem.

I can confirm that this file and its symbolic link both have at least xx4 permission. And if I directly put that file into `/etc/dnscrypt-proxy` directory, it works.

So could anyone tell me what is the root cause? And if I want to follow the symbolic link form, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `ProtectHome=yes` enabled.

> If true, the directories /home, /root, and /run/user are made inaccessible and empty for processes invoked by this unit. If set to "read-only", the three directories are made read-only instead.

---

To change this setting in a packaged unit file,

- you can copy the entire unit file to `/etc/systemd/system/<name>.service` and edit it there (/etc takes priority over /usr/lib);
- you can create an "add-on" file `/etc/systemd/system/<name>.service.d/whatever.conf` that just updates the settings you need:

  ```
  [Service]
  ProtectHome=read-only
  ```
- you can use `systemctl edit [--full] <name>` as a shortcut to do either of the above automatically;
- as a *last resort*, you can use your package manager's configuration (e.g. NoUpgrade or dpkg-divert) to exclude the file in /usr/lib from being upgraded.

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed that this is the root cause. And do you have any idea about how to fix this problem without touching the service file? As it will be overwritten when upgrading.

Comment: try creating a data directory outside your home (you can call it "personal" if you like, and set ownership/priv accordingly, and even link it back to your home). but unless you want to edit the service file, you will have to link to a location outside of `/home`.

Comment: @Sraw: Use one of the documented methods for editing a service file, and/or for excluding a packaged file from upgrades... There's `/etc/systemd` and `systemctl edit [--full]` for a start.